# Where are game saves stored in Ubuntu?

Tags: games, steam

I just installed Ubuntu and I am getting used to it,
On Windows everything was stored in Documents folder for me, so I just copied that entire folder, but now I noticed that the new game saves are not stored in Documents from Ubuntu, so I do not know where to put save game files.

Comment: Is this wine (windows) games, or Ubuntu games?

Comment: It is Wine games

Comment: Wine games installed from steam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have GTA San Andreas on my system, the save file located on `~/Documents` folder, because wine link Windows `My Documents` to `$HOME/Documents`'s Ubuntu.

You can see list of wine desktop integration by running `winecfg`, then click **Desktop Integration** tab.

[image]

But, if you run the games installed from steam, then the configuration file/saved file etc. should be stored on `.local/share/steam`, just crawl through it and you're gonna find it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no longer *steam* directory in *~/.local/share*.
I found my saves (for *Life is Strange: Before the Strom*) in **~/.local/share/feral-interactive (developer name)**.

I installed Steam through Ubuntu repository (at least "Steam isntaller"), not using *wine*.

For me the easiest way to find it turned out to be just typing a game name into the search box in file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the new location is:
`~/.steam/steam/steamapps/compatdata/<gameid>/pfx/`

Or if you set a Library location, it will be there under:
 `SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/<gameid>/pfx/`.

The game ID numbers are 6 or 7 digit numbers.